# Problem in AVAUDIORECORDER detection

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudiorecorder

I want to detect voice of any buddy(Note: i am not going to press any button just sense the voice and start recording) User can speak and my application detect sound automatically and when the user stop talking, the sound automatically play..How can i do this, I have done recording by pressing button Record,Stop and Play..But how can i sense..Its a problem for me...
here is the code...

```
#import "recordViewController.h"

@implementation recordViewController
@synthesize playButton, stopButton, recordButton;

-(void) recordAudio
{
     if (!audioRecorder.recording)
     {
             playButton.enabled = NO;
             stopButton.enabled = YES;
             [audioRecorder record];
     }
}
-(void)stop
{
    stopButton.enabled = NO;
    playButton.enabled = YES;
    recordButton.enabled = YES;

    if (audioRecorder.recording)
    {
            [audioRecorder stop];
    } else if (audioPlayer.playing) {
            [audioPlayer stop];
    }
}
-(void) playAudio
{
    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
       stopButton.enabled = YES;
       recordButton.enabled = NO;

        if (audioPlayer)
              [audioPlayer release];
        NSError *error;

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
        initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url                                    
        error:&error];

        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", 
              [error localizedDescription]);
        else
              [audioPlayer play];
   }
}
.
.
.
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/